# How can I get emacs to keep my isearch strings highlighted?

Tags: emacs

How can I get emacs to highlight the phrase I'm searching for and then keep it highlighted until I search for another phrase? Can it do this transparently i.e. just by searching, not having to run another command afterwards (like  `isearch-highlight-regexp`) ?

Comment: Interesting question - never found the need for it, can see how it'd be useful, but could also see how it'd be annoying. Looking forward to seeing an answer.

Comment: I like to use it to see easily where a variable is being set and used. Linking it to search makes sense to me and it's easy to move onto something else by searching for the next variable

Comment: Nice - can see how that'd be useful

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this:

```
(setq lazy-highlight-cleanup nil)
```

If you want to clear out the highlight manually, do <kbd>M-x lazy-highlight-cleanup</kbd>

Comment: That did the trick. I also had to set:
`(setq lazy-highlight-max-at-a-time nil)` and `(setq lazy-highlight-initial-delay 0)` to get the exact effect that I wanted.

Comment: Trey's answer is the right one -- that's the purpose of the variable `lazy-highlight-cleanup`. And yes, this is a useful feature. Not one that everyone will use everyday, but useful sometimes. FWIW, I have the same option for **Icicles** search, for the same reasons. But I also agree that, depending on what you really want, you might want to look at highlighting patterns in other ways. See, for example:
<http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighLight>

Comment: It would be nice to have on-search highlights that clear automatically when mouse clicked in the buffer, while they stick when scrolling. The sticky highlights pointed out here are useful for some cases but would be annoying to have on all the time. The less sticky style is the default in Netbeans IIRC.

Comment: How do you make the highlights highlight in all of the buffer, not just in the are visible on the screen at the time of search? With the `(setq lazy-highlight-cleanup nil)` approach I don't get any highlights when I scroll to other parts of the buffer.

Answer (score 5):

Trey's answer seems to work. I thought I'd include one using advice just for the sake of completeness:

```
(defadvice isearch-exit (after ysph-hl-search activate compile)
  "after isearch, highlight the search term "
  (highlight-regexp (car (if isearch-regexp
                             regexp-search-ring
                           search-ring)) (find-face 'hi-pink)))
```

Answer (score 1):

This variant combines lazy-highlight with regex highlighting once you're done with the search. This resembles the `hlsearch` behavior of vim in emacs.

```lisp
(setq lazy-highlight t                 ; highlight occurrences
      lazy-highlight-cleanup nil       ; keep search term highlighted
      lazy-highlight-max-at-a-time nil ; all occurences in file
      isearch-allow-scroll t           ; continue the search even though we're scrolling
      )

;; when exiting isearch, register the search term as regexp-highlight
(defadvice isearch-done (after ysph-hl-search activate compile)
           "highlight the search term after isearch has quit"
           (unhighlight-regexp t)
           (highlight-regexp (car (if isearch-regexp
                                      regexp-search-ring
                                      search-ring)) 'lazy-highlight))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to just use highlight-phrase or highlight-regexp, and not depend on the search system doing the job at all.

Comment: That's exactly what I said I didn't want. I want to hook into search  because I want to find the next match and highlight all the matches with one command.